# How can i style the picker in react native

Tags: react-native

i have this picker i set for it the borderColor and the backgrondColor but it doesn't work   , also how can i set style for  Picker.item ?
here is my code

```
 <Picker dataSource={this.state.x}
   style={{borderColor:'red' , backgroundColor:'green'}} // doesn't work 

      >

     {this.state.x.map((value)=><Picker.Item label={value} value={value} />)} 

     </Picker>
```

Comment: What do you mean by style the Picker.item? The docs say that, "itemStyle" can only be used for iOS and not for Android

Answer (score 6):

I've created a sample Snack as a possible solution to the issue.

https://snack.expo.io/@incorelabs/style-picker-android

Apparently on Android you need to wrap the Picker in a parent view and apply a border and background color to that. I hope this is the desired outcome you were looking for.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Picker } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    language: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          borderColor: 'red',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop: 100,
          marginLeft: 100,
          width: 200,
        }}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.language}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            color: 'white',
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
            this.setState({ language: itemValue })
          }>
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Picker with Border and Background Color on Android]